# Сбрасываются данные предыдущих компонентов при добавлении новых

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="submit" name="" id="add">
 <div id="elements"> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function (e) {
   counter++;
   $("#elements").html($("#elements").html()+
   '<input type="text" name="" id="input-'+counter+'">');
   $("#input-"+counter).val("10");
  });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, добавляется новое поле. В нём должно быть значение по умолчанию 10. Почему данные предыдущих полей сбрасываются? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `.append()` вместо `.html()`:

```js
var counter = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
  counter++;
  $("#elements").append('<input type="text" name="" id="input-' + counter + '">');
  $("#input-" + counter).val("10");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="" id="add">
<div id="elements"> </div>
```